# gitignore'd file keeps getting listed as untracked

Tags: git

I have a directory listing that looks like this (this is the root of my repo):

```
.git
.gitignore
MORE FILES / FOLDERS
_viminfo
```

My .gitignore looks like this:

```
/_viminfo
```

Everything, including the .gitignore, has been long commited and everything. However, when I type `git status` I still get this output:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       _viminfo
```

What could be the culprit of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a trailing space after `/_viminfo` in the `.gitignore`, removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
./_viminfo
```

or to remove from whole project...

```
_viminfo
```

and make sure there are no trailing spaces after the filenames ;)

Comment: in .gitignore files, the forward slash at the beginning of a path indicates the root of the repo, not the drive

Comment: `_viminfo` does work, but that ignores it anywhere in the project. The strange this is is that this commit fixed it. I have __no clue__ what was the cause of this: https://github.com/nightcracker/dotfiles/commit/bc53abc88f896fa90afd18c1a112e69a6cb7e5a8

Comment: @nightcracker looks like there was a trailing space after the filename, and that commit removed it. Maybe that is what caused the issue.